# How do I implement a button to call a method in a separate class in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, graphics

I'm working on an Android experiment that's supposed to randomly generate color pallets. The user customizes how many cells the pallet has, and then pressed the dice button to randomize the colors of each pallet to generate a visually pleasant color pallet.

For now, I'm only attempting to implement a button that's supposed to add a cell to the palletView (from the class Cells.java). For now, I have the cellCount data field initialized to 5, and as a test, the button is supposed to call the addCell() method, where it changes the cellCount to 6. I ran the emulator, but the button won't respond. No crashing nor errors, it just does nothing.

Here's are some screenshots with notes illustrating the current state and supposed functionality of this app

[Emulater Screenshot 1 - 5 Cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJzvy.png)

[Emulator Screenshot 2 - 6 Cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vs1NM.png)

Code for Cells.java. This class and it's functions work, I just couldn't get them to be controlled by the imageButton

```
package com.dexfenik.palletdice;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class Cells extends View {

// INITIALIZE THE CELL COUNTER (DEFAULT IS 5 FOR TEST)
private int cellCount = 5;

// INITIALIZE THE VALUES FOR THE COLOR CELLS
private Paint paint = new Paint();

// DATA FIELDS FOR GETTING SCREEN DENSITY FOR FIXED CELL SIZES
private Display display = ((Activity) getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
private float screenWidth = display.getWidth();
private float screenHeight = display.getHeight();
private final float top = 0;
private final float bottom = screenHeight/2;

public Cells (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public void oneCell(Canvas canvas) {...}      // DRAWS ONE PALLET CELL IN THE PALLETVIEW

public void twoCells(Canvas canvas) {...}     // DRAWS TWO CELLS IN THE PALLETVIEW

public void threeCells(Canvas canvas) {...}   // DRAWS THREE CELLS IN THE PALLETVIEW

public void fourCells(Canvas canvas) {...}    // DRAWS FOUR CELLS IN THE PALLETVIEW

public void fiveCells(Canvas canvas) {...}    // DRAWS FIVE CELLS IN THE PALLETVIEW

public void sixCells(Canvas canvas) {...}     // DRAWS SIX CELLS IN THE PALLETVIEW

//###################################################
                                                 // #
// INCREMENT CELL COUNT WITH + BUTTON            // #
public void addCell(View view) {                 // # <-- THE BUTTON IS SUPPOSED TO RUN THIS METHOD
                                                 // #     (cellCount is 6 as a test)
    cellCount = 6;                               // #
}                                                // #
//###################################################

// DECREMENT CELL COUNT WITH - BUTTON
public void removeCell() {...}

//###################################################
                                                 // #
@Override                                        // #
public void onDraw (Canvas canvas) {             // #
                                                 // #
    switch (cellCount){                          // #
        case 1: oneCell(canvas);                 // #
            break;                               // #
        case 2: twoCells(canvas);                // #
            break;                               // #
        case 3: threeCells(canvas);              // #
            break;                               // #
        case 4: fourCells(canvas);               // #
            break;                               // #
        case 5: fiveCells(canvas);               // #
            break;                               // #
        case 6: sixCells(canvas);                // # <-- WHEN "cellCount" IS 6, THERE WILL BE SIX COLOR CELLS
    }                                            // #     (This method works when the cellCount variable is changed,
}                                                // #      but I can't get the button to implement that)
}                                                    // #
//###################################################
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.dexfenik.palletdice;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.content.Context;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Cells cells;
private View view;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    cells = new Cells(this, null);
    setContentView(cells);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageButton addCellBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.addCell);
    //ImageButton removeCellBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.subCell);   // NOT YET IMPLEMENTED
    //ImageButton diceBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.randomBtn);       // NOT YET IMPLEMENTED

    //##############################################################
                                                                // #
    // TRYING TO GET THE ADD BUTTON TO WORK                     // #
    addCellBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  // #
        @Override                                               // #
        public void onClick(View v) {                           // #
                cells.addCell(v);                               // # <-- THIS IS WHERE I'M TRYING TO GET THE BUTTON TO WORK
        }                                                       // #
    });                                                         // #
}                                                               // #
                                                                // #
    //##############################################################

}
```

activity_my.xml, where I built the imageButton. I'll have this here in case there's anything I've missed in the layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.dexfenik.palletdice.MainActivity">

    <!-- LAYOUT FOR PALLET CELLS -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/palletView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5">


        <com.dexfenik.palletdice.Cells
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- LAYOUT FOR CONTROLS -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/controlView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="#1f1f1f">

        <!-- IMAGEBUTTON FOR ADDCELL -->
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/addCell"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/plus"
            android:contentDescription="@string/add"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:onClick="addCell"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

If I can get help on how I can get this button implemented, it will answer a lot of my questions on how java graphics can be controlled from a separate view. Thank you.

UPDATE: Turns out I used View as my parameter for addCell, rather than the variable it declared. I'm still having the same issue though

Comment: You need to trigger a measure and draw for the View (call requestLayout() in the addCell() method).

Comment: Does you onclcik works just put some log and check then you need only to work with Cells class , and  setContentView(cells);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); twice i'am not sure you can do this

Answer (score 0):

In the function call, inside onClick, view is a not initialized parameter. Perhaps you meant to write cells.addCell(v)?

Comment: Another thought, private variables are supposed to be visible only to the class in which they are declared. Try changing definition:
    private Cells cells; 
to
    public Cells cells;

Answer (score 0):

```
addCellBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  // #
    @Override                                               // #
    public void onClick(View v) {                           // #
            cells.addCell(v);                            // # <-- THIS IS WHERE I'M TRYING TO GET THE BUTTON TO WORK
    }                                                       // #
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but that still didn't work. I still got the same issue

Comment: Put the Log.d in Button click and see if that is printing in logcat

Answer (score 0):

You should try this way,
When you create `cells = new Cells(this, null);` at this place pass Image button in Cells constructer.
Then, set click listener of Image button in `Cells class`,
You will get click event in `Cells class`.